# conntrack in iptables not working

Tags: iptables

I have tried to use conntrack in my iptables rules, however I keep getting an error. I've tried aminimal example with just one line and the error appears as well.

```
admin@server:/home/admin/skrypty# iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --cstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables v1.4.21: unknown option "--cstate"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

It appears everything related to conntrack fails. What did I do wrong?

my uname -a:

`3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Google yields zero results so I guess it's very rare and small mistake on my side. I have installed apt-get install conntrack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option's name is `--ctstate` not `--cstate`.

Comment: Thank you so much - I've been staring at this like a zombie since morning trying to search through packages. I had a feeling it's something small. Thanks again.